# Trying to use react-admin transform function on <Create />

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, use-context, use-reducer

I'm new to react-admin and I am trying to build a custom image gallery input. it should show a modal with images (data is already fetched and stored in the redux) so the user can select one or more images (upon selection an action is dispatched to update the reducer's value) and I need these selected images ids in the transform function on `<Create />` so I can add the required data before dataProvider method is called.

but I have a weird issue, that might be because of my lack of react knowledge. in the snippet below, I try to get the `useReducer`s value and then add it to the form.

```
import React, { useReducer, useMemo, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Create as Ra_create } from 'react-admin';

const ctxInitialValues = {};

const galleryCtx = React.createContext(ctxInitialValues);

const CreateWithGallery = (props) => {
    const [selectedImages, dispatch] = useReducer((state, { type, payload }) => {
        switch (type) {
            case 'UPDATE_STATE':
                return { ...payload };
            case 'INIT_RECORD':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    [payload]: [],
                };
            default:
                return state;
        }
    }, ctxInitialValues);

    const updateSelection = (record, image, operation) => {
        if (operation === 'add') {
            let newState = {
                ...selectedImages,
                [record]: [...selectedImages[record], image],
            };
            dispatch({
                type: 'UPDATE_STATE',
                payload: newState,
            });
        } else if (operation === 'remove') {
            let newState = {
                ...selectedImages,
                [record]: selectedImages[record].filter((item) => item.id !== image.id),
            };
            dispatch({
                type: 'UPDATE_STATE',
                payload: newState,
            });
        }
    };

    const transformPayload = (data) => {
        let transformed = {
            ...data,
        };
        // but I get {} here
        for (let record in selectedImages) {
            transformed[record] = selectedImages[record].map((item) => ({
                id: item.id,
            }));
        }
        return transformed;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(selectedImages);
        // I get fresh values here
    }, [selectedImages]);

    const initializeRecord = (record) => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'INIT_RECORD',
            payload: record,
        });
    };

    return (
        <galleryCtx.Provider
            value={{
                selectedImages,
                updateSelection,
                initializeRecord,
            }}
        >
            <Ra_create {...props} transform={transformPayload}>
                {props.children}
            </Ra_create>
        </galleryCtx.Provider>
    );
};

export { galleryCtx };
export default CreateWithGallery;
```

when I try to access the selectedImages values in the transform function I get {}, which is the initial state. I have tried using useCallback and useMemo to make sure the values are changed after each dispatch but it did not make any difference.
there's also a similar behavior in this question as well:
[React Admin: how to pass state to transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699005/react-admin-how-to-pass-state-to-transform)

how can I use state in the transform function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with setting the transform prop on the  component (in custom toolbar):

```
 const CustomToolbar = (props: any) => {

        const transform = useCallback((data: any) => {
            return {
                ...data,
                files: something_from_state,
            };
        }, [something_from_state]);


        const handleClick = () => {
        };


        return <Toolbar {...props}>
            <SaveButton
                handleSubmitWithRedirect={handleClick} transform={transform}/>
        </Toolbar>
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

to fix this you can use transform prop on  as explained in the [react-admin docs](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#altering-the-form-values-before-submitting). it is still unclear though, why we can't get state in the transform function on the  or .