# Why we can't get state in the transform function

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

In react-admin I want alter the form before submit, add variable from state. But value of variable is remain initial and I can't set it to actual. There is a code snippet below. How can I achieve my goal?

```
const MyComponent = props => {
    // setSomeVariable will be called elsewhere, so the value of someVariable will be changed
    const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState('initial')

    const transform = data => {
        data['someVariable'] = someVariable  //it's value will remain 'initial'. How to set actual value?
        return data
    }

    return <Create {...props} transform={transform}>
           ...
           </Create>
}
```

Similar behavior was in these questions, but they were not answered:

[Trying to use react-admin transform function on <Create />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563954/trying-to-use-react-admin-transform-function-on-create/66763790#66763790)

[React Admin: how to pass state to transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699005/react-admin-how-to-pass-state-to-transform)

Thanks.

Comment: You have to use ``setSomeVariable`` to update the state

Comment: `setSomeVariable` is calling in other place, in other component and in react devtools I can see how value of `someVariable` has updated. But in `transform` function value of `someVariable` is initial. @Josh

Comment: Also, may be I described not clearly enough, but I want add new property to `data` not retrieve :)

Comment: Answer from this question [Trying to use react-admin transform function on <Create />](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563954/trying-to-use-react-admin-transform-function-on-create?noredirect=1&lq=1) helped me.

Answer (score 0):

use `setSomeVariable` to update the state

```
const MyComponent = props => {
  // setVariable will be called elsewhere, so the value of someVariable will be changed
  const [someVariable, setSomeVariable] = useState('initial')

  const transform = data => {
    const newSomeVariable  = data['someVariable'] //it's value will remain 'initial'. How to set actual value?
    setSomeVariable(newSomeVariable);
    return data
  }

  return <Create {...props} transform={transform}>
    ...
           </Create>
}
```